# How do I limit pyqt4 clipboard just only print text or image path?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

```
  def tt(self):
    cb=QApplication.clipboard()
    data=cb.mimeData()
    #if data.hasImage():
            #for path in data.urls():
                #print path

    if data.hasText():
        tex =unicode (data.text())
        print tex
        if tex != "":
            r = QtCore.QStringList([])
            for ct in tex:
                py = slug(ct, style=pypinyin.TONE, errors='ignore')
                if py != '':
                    w = ct + '(' + py + ')'
                else:
                    w = ct
                r.append(w)
            str = r.join("")
        self.ui.textEdit.setText(QtCore.QString(str))
```

I use python2.7 and pyqt4 to make something like Chinese characters to Pinyin. So when I copy string, it's fine, the job ding very well. but when I copy image, I just want only print its path . but tex still work, slug() will go error. how do I limit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QMimeData.hasUrls()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmimedata.html#hasUrls) and [QMimeData.urls()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmimedata.html#urls). The latter returns a list of [QUrl](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qurl.html) objects (which are also used for file-paths):

```
if data.hasUrls() or data.hasImage():
    for url in data.urls():
        filepath = unicode(url.toLocalFile())
        print(filepath)
elif data.hasText():
    tex =unicode (data.text())
    ...
```

**EDIT**:

Here is a test script to get clipboard information:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Get Clipboard Info', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.edit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        cb = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()
        data = cb.mimeData()
        output = []
        if data.hasImage():
            image = QtGui.QImage(data.imageData())
            output.append('Image: size %s' % image.byteCount())
        elif data.hasUrls():
            output.append('Urls: count %s' % len(data.urls()))
            for url in data.urls():
                filepath = unicode(url.toLocalFile())
                output.append('  %s' % filepath)
        elif data.hasText():
            output.append('Text: length %s' % len(data.text()))
        output.append('')
        output.append('Formats: count %s' % len(data.formats()))
        for fmt in data.formats():
            output.append('  %s' % fmt)
        self.edit.setText('\n'.join(output))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 50, 300, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: But tex =unicode (data.text())  still has some data . py = slug(ct, style=pypinyin.TONE, errors='ignore')  still has an error. I want to get the file path at the same time tex does not work.

Comment: If the mimedata has urls, use the urls **instead of** the text.

Comment: @谦一吴. I have added a test script to my answer. Please run it and try copying text, images and urls (e.g. from a file manager). When I run it, I see different information for each one, and everything works correctly. What output do you see?

Comment: @谦一吴. Please accept my answer if you found it useful (i..e click on the tick symbol).